# Will having two different versions of a DLL cause issues?

Tags: dll, vb6

I have a vb6 program that needs to use MSOLAP80.dll to display its pivot tables properly.  But because MSOLAP90.dll has some compatibility issues with this I cannot use MSOLAP90.dll and still have the pivot tables display.

I have registered MSOLAP90.dll and then registered MSOLAP80.dll again and everything seems to be fine.  I however don't know if both are actually registered or if MSOLAP80.dll is the only one registered, because I have no reference point as to what is new in MSOLAP90.dll.  Is it possible that both are registered and the program is just using MSOLAP80.dll and if there are programs that need MSOLAP90.dll then it will know to use that one?

I guess I am just confused about how registering DLL's work and if it is possible to have both of these registered at the same time. Can somebody help with an explanation?

Comment: It depends on the DLLs and what they implement. Essentially, objects will be created using the last one registered. If you only use version 8.0 objects, then they'll only come from version 8 of the DLL. If you use a version 9.0 object, it may try and load it from the 90 dll, or just fail outright.

Comment: My program only uses the version 8 objects but I am curious if having both would effect other programs as well?

Comment: Registering the DLL without also recompiling your program shows that these DLLs use the same guids.  That's a problem, you will very likely break any program that requires msolap90.dll to work correctly.  This kind of ancient code is best run in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know for sure which one is registered, you can:

- Look at the References dialogue for a type library which matches your DLLs' paths.
- Open up RegEdit, and search for MSOLAP80.DLL or MSOLAP90.DLL (uncheck "Match whole string only").

If you find references for both DLLs, then you are safe because you can bind to a specific version. If you find a reference to the wrong DLL, then unregister the wrong one, and register the right one.

COM originall only allowed one version of a set of CLSIDs (which uniquely identify classes), IIDs (which uniquely identify classes' interfaces) at any one time. It is possible to have more than one reference to a LIBID (which identifies a type library - a resource embedded in the DLLL) but they have to have different versions.

From Windows XP onwards, it became possible to do side by side DLL access in which an executable can access a specific version of a DLL, overriding the value in the registry. You need to embed or have a .manifest file in the same folder as the EXE file.

Unfortunately, the documentation for this seems to have disappeared from MSDN, and is only referred to by a couple of Knowledge Base articles:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828629
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843524